# Please explain the following sorting function

Tags: php, sorting

This function sorts the array in increasing order of their elements size, if size is equal then sorts on the basis of dictionary order.

Please someone help, Thanks in advance :)

```
    function lensort($a,$b){
    $la = strlen( $a); 
    $lb = strlen( $b);
    if( $la == $lb) {
        return strcmp( $a, $b);
    }
    return $la - $lb;
}

usort($array,'lensort');

 I appreciate the responses, but i want if someone can just write a code to do the same task, not using inbuilt function
```

Comment: Sort an array of strings by length; if strings are of equal length, then sort them alphabetically.... so what's the question?

Comment: Which part of the function is confusing you? There are only 5 lines, none of them do anything complicated.

Comment: "I appreciate the responses, but i want if someone can just write a code to do the same task, not using inbuilt function" - That's not an appropriate request for SO.

Comment: I marked you down, because an appropriate request for SO is mot to get someone to write your code, but to assist and collaborate on issues related to programming. I suggest to try something, then when you are having difficulties, post here, so someone can help get past the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Functions passed to usort are expected to return an integer less than zero if `$a` is less than `$b`, 0 if `$a == $b` and greater than 0 if `$a` is greater than `$b`.

In this case it's using `$la - $lb` since this will return an approriate integer based on the difference in length of `$a` and `$b`. If the length is the same then `strcmp` is used which will also return an approriate integer.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly like this:

```
// declare the function
function lensort($a,$b){
// Set $LA to the length of string $a
$la = strlen( $a); 

// Set $Lb to the length of string $b
$lb = strlen( $b);

// If both strings are of equal length
if( $la == $lb) {
   // Return a neg or pos number based on which of the two strings is larger, alfabetically seen
    return strcmp( $a, $b);
}
// If not the same length, just return the size of one minus the other
return $la - $lb;
}

// Use usort to perform a person function-based sorting routine on the input data.
usort($array,'lensort');
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function sorts a given array by values using a user-defined comparison function.

The user-defined function must return

- 0 if its arguments are equal
- integer value less than zero if its first argument is less than second
- integer value greater than zero if its first argument is greater than second

In your code snippet this user-defined comparison function is `lensort`, which compares given strings by their lengths.